# How can I display an Alert view from view model in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I working on Xamarin hybrid application, right now I am using MVVM architecture. My view model is 'INotifyPropertyChanged' interface class. I parse json data on this viewmodel class. Now I want to display alert if failed to read json data from server or need to show error message to user on Alert. But it not working. I know 'DisplayAlert()' will work only on Page Classes. So how can I show the alert from ViewModel Page. I tried this also, but not working;

```cs
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constant.KSorry, Constant.KNoDataAvailable, Constant.KOK);
```

Comment: Did you try putting the code inside --- Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: Thanks @hashimks,  No I will try and update you

Comment: What's not working? There's an exception triggered? The dialog is not showing? The text is wrong? We'll need more information (and code) to determine what's going on. The snippet you've written should work fine.

Comment: It work using main thread - Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. I will add the code in answer

Comment: Shall I post it as answer?

Comment: Thanks @hashimks, it work

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting the code inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`

like,

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
   await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hello", "message", "OK");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Displaying an alert from main thread should work from ViewModel 'INotifyPropertyChanged' Interface class. Check the code

```
if (arrayAlbumList == null) {
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constant.KSorry, 
                Constant.KNoDataAvailable, Constant.KOK);
   });
}
else {
  // binding the object here using array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On MVVM we can try the following

1. When you have just one button on the alert

`DeviceDevice.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {     await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hello", "message", "OK"); });`

2. When you have more than one button on the alert dialog

var response = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hello", "message", "OK", Cancel");

No need for Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread in this case